# Alternative or workaround for wp_insert_attachment

Tags: uploads, woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating a woocommerce product programmatically. Sadly, these products sometimes has about 8-12 variations with attributes. I also want to attach an image to these variations and as far as I found the only way is to use wp_insert_attachment

```
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $post_info[$key], $file_name, $variant);

update_post_meta($variant, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
```

The problem with this is that UI freezes for too long when this is performed. It actually sometimes takes more than two minutes which, of course, is not acceptable.

How would you suggest to approach such performance issue or maybe I could somehow upload differently? I do not need a working sample. Just thoughts on how I could approach this. Thanks a lot!